# How do I fix Undefined array key "js" in whmcs?

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, whmcs

Hi everyone im new here,

recently I decided to setup my own automated hosting service.

The issue I have now is with the whmcs-bridge plugin.

Everytime I would click 'continue' to test the checkout on my bridged website, it would always come up a blank page that just said something along the lines of [woo_commerce].

It was taking a page from my main wordpress website and was redirecting there instead of to the normal whmcs checkout.

So I deleted that page and now i get a 404 error. I then went into my php ini settings and enabled debugging and two warnings appear

(Removed full paths for security.)

(Warning: Undefined array key "raw" in /whmcs-bridge/includes/request.class.php on line 477)
(Warning: Undefined array key "js" in /whmcs-bridge/includes/parser.inc.php on line 275)

The second warning is appearing for the checkout so this is what is causing it from making that 404 error.

Here is line 477 of request.class.php ---->  `$this->data = $data['raw'];`

Here is line 275 of parser.inc.php

```
if (stristr($_REQUEST['js'], 'vmware') !== false && stristr($_REQUEST['js'], 'console.php') !== false) {
```

Im not good with code at all so any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Steven

Comment: I am not sure about the implication of the code but you can check if the value is set and not empty before both lines by `if (isset($data['raw']) && !empty($data['raw'])) {` and `if (isset($_REQUEST['js']) && !empty($_REQUEST['js'])) {`